# Coverting a UserControl to WebUserControl in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, winforms, webusercontrol

I would like to know is there a possibility to convert a `winforms usercontrol` to `web user control` so that I need to use that control in my webpage.

If it is possible how do I need to start?And Can anyone guide me through some articles?As I have seen one of the article from codeproject but I couldn't understand well!

Here is the link for that article which I have followed.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Usercontrol_to_WebControl.aspx

Answer (score 4):

ASP.Net and WinForms are radically different.

You should rewrite the control from scratch.

Comment: No other possibility?As I am having a canvas with some scrollars and I think it needs a lot of conversion.

Comment: You are correct; it needs a lot of conversion.  You will need to learn HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to convert a winforms control to a server control. You'll have to completely rebuild the control for the web. The rendering mechanisms are completely different, and the web is stateless, which means that development needs to center around and work within the ASP.NET page lifecycle to maintain state across postbacks. Because of this, developing web-based controls tends to be much more complicated.

You can use the winforms control as inspiration when designing the server control equivalent, but that's pretty much where it ends.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I am on my way in building web user control from scratch.